# Get latest record from second table left joined to first table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a candidate table say `candidates` having only `id` field and i left joined `profiles` table to it. Table `profiles` has 2 fields namely, `candidate_id` & `name`.

e.g. Table `candidates`:

```
 id
 ----
 1
 2
```

and Table `profiles`:

```
 candidate_id      name
 ----------------------------
      1           Foobar
      1           Foobar2
      2           Foobar3
```

i want the latest name of a candidate in a single query which is given below:

```
SELECT C.id, P.name 
  FROM   candidates C
LEFT JOIN profiles P ON P.candidate_id = C.id 
GROUP BY C.id 
ORDER BY P.name;
```

But this query returns:

```
1     Foobar
2     Foobar3
```

...Instead of:

```
1     Foobar2
2     Foobar3
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `PROFILES` table doesn't provide a reliable means of figuring out what the latest `name` value is.  There are two options for the `PROFILES` table:

1. Add a datetime column IE: `created_date`
2. Define an auto_increment column

The first option is the best - it's explicit, meaning the use of the column is absolutely obvious, and handles backdated entries better.

```
ALTER TABLE PROFILES ADD COLUMN created_date DATETIME
```

If you want the value to [default to the current date & time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) when inserting a record if no value is provided, tack the following on to the end:

```
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

With that in place, you'd use the following to get your desired result:

```
   SELECT c.id, 
          p.name 
     FROM CANDIDATES c
LEFT JOIN PROFILES p ON p.candidate_id = c.id 
     JOIN (SELECT x.candidate_id,
                  MAX(x.created_date) AS max_date
             FROM PROFILES x
         GROUP BY x.candidate_id) y ON y.candidate_id = p.candidate_id
                                   AND y.max_date = p.created_date
 GROUP BY c.id 
 ORDER BY p.name
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT C.id, (SELECT P.name FROM profiles P WHERE P.candidate_id = C.id ORDER BY P.name LIMIT 1);
```